# Android L - BLE scancallback in background

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-5.0-lollipop

I have created a very simple application that scans and vibrates for each BLE advertising detect (with scancallback). This application works well but my problem is that when the smartphone turns in standby mode, the application stops. Do I have to create a service? or are there others solutions with Android L and his new API BLE?

Comment: Is anybody can help me?

Comment: Please consider the answer in this forum: stackoverflow.com/questions/19914244/creating-background-services-for-bluetooth-low-energy-on-android